# Lost TeeChart / TChart in Delphi XE2 when installing Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, teechart, delphi-xe4

Installing Delphi XE4 wiped out (at least it happened at the same time) all my Delphi XE2 components. I have since then installed packages again, and most seems to be working again.

However, I have some problems with TChart /TeeChart that is bundled with Delphi. I tried to add the "teexxx" packages I could find, but none of hem were designtime packages apparently.

I then tried to download "TeeChart Standard Edition based on Update 4 Available to Delphi XE2, C++Builder XE2 and RAD Studio XE2 registered user" ... It seemling installed fine without errors, but the components are still not available in the Delphi IDE.

Anyhow, I guess I must have been trying to install the wrong teexxx packages, so, well, does anyone know which I still try add as package in the Delphi XE2 IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The design time package for the TeeChart Standard component shipped with XE2 is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\dcltee9160.bpl`.

You can install it manually through the "Add..." buton in the list of packages at the "Component\Isntall Packages..." menu.

Answer (score 7):

In Tokyo, Teechart is an optional extra in the installer. You can add it if you missed it by using Tools-->Manage Platforms-->Additional Options-->Teechart Standard

Comment: I was crazing... I didn't check teechart when I was installing Delphi xe11.2. after installing all components (the worst step on installing Delphi) it warns the need to teechart.